# Querying Teradata tables from within MySQL Scripts

Tags: mysql, teradata

I am running data analyses using a MySQL database. I need to connect to multiple sources / other databases (Teradata and Hive) to retrieve / refresh the source data in my database.

So far I have been exporting the data in the source databases and importing the csv files into my MySQL database, but this is

(a) time consuming

(b) does not always work even via Load Infile (it sometimes crashes for some files with no apparent reason)

and (c) it is not really good data practice to persist the data in every environment you need to extract insights out of it.

Is it possible to query Teradata tables (and Hive tables) from within a MySQL environment using a ODBC (or other)?

I am aware of virtualisation tools and other ETL / middleware but these are not open source.

I am not the DBA of either the MySQL or the Teradata tables, but I spoke to the DBAs and they do not know how to help me.

Comment: *"I am not the DBA of either the MySQL or the Teradata tables, but I spoke to the DBAs and they do not know how to help me."* MySQL does not natively support ANSI/ISO SQL/MED ("Management of External Data")  in anyway..   Unless MariaDB [connect engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect/) can run on MySQL which i doubt also not helpfull as you don't have acces to the RDMS i assume to install a plugin and also assuming those remote RDMS can be accessed online..

Comment: .. but you could offcource try to install MariaDB locally and try with the CONNECT engine, i believe CONNECT engine can directly read cvs files without importing by the way..

Comment: Also you could be able to cheat with MySQL [The CSV Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html) by creating the table stucture and copy your cvs into the path location where MySQL created that table..  Notice the manual says -> *"This format can be read, and even written, by spreadsheet applications such as Microsoft Excel or StarOffice Calc. "* meaning any valid CVS file on that location should be readable by MySQL..

Comment: What kind of data analysis are you running on MySQL? MySQL doesn't support linked servers, but you should try to run your analysis on Hive/TD (both should process much faster than MySQL) and export only the result(s).